# implicit declaration of function ‘va_start’

Tags: c, linux, gcc, variadic-functions

**EDIT:** I now have `#include <stdarg.h>` and it compiles - but the varargs don't get passed. Any ideas why?

---

I have this code (excerpt):

```
void msg(char* message, ...) {
    va_list args;
    va_start(args, message);
    char* m;
    if(asprintf(&m, message, args)==-1) m = message;
    va_end(args);

    print("<fg:green>INFO:</fg> ");
    println(m);
}
```

(`print` and `printf` are wrappers that do the color tags)

The idea was to pass on varargs to asprintf.

However, it doesn't compile:

```
gcc -g -Wall -std=gnu99 -O2 -Wfatal-errors   -c -o src/ui.o src/ui.c
src/ui.c: In function ‘msg’:
src/ui.c:7:5: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘va_start’ [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
src/ui.c:12:5: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘va_end’ [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
```

Do I have to include something special to get `va_start()` and `va_end()`?

---

GCC (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.6.3-1ubuntu5) 4.6.3
Xubuntu 12.04

Comment: #include <stdarg.h> ?

Comment: Yeah, I added it - now it compiles, but doesn't seem to work. any ideas? As if the varargs disappeared.

Comment: How would *you* feel if your employer said, "it doesn't work; fix it or be fired" and wouldn't give you *any* other information?

Comment: @KerrekSB what do you mean? I said what doesn't work - the varargs don't get passed. And please undo your downvote, it's not fair.

Comment: No. *You* explain what you expect, what actually happens and what diagnostics you have produced, and *then* we talk. This is unanswerable as it stands, let alone useless for the community. At the very least show how `asprintf` is defined.

Comment: Know what? Just move on if you don't want to help, and don't be rude.

Comment: @KerrekSB and btw `asprintf()` is a [standard GNU-C function](http://linux.die.net/man/3/asprintf)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You have to include `#include <stdarg.h>` and use `vasprintf` instead of `asprintf`.